# Ошибка при запуске webpack

Tags: webpack

Ошибка
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found. Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.﻿

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack-template for frontend",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "http-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "stiv",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: А как запускаешь `webpack`?

Comment: И не плохо было бы посмотреть на сам `webpack-config.js`

Comment: у вас входного  файла нету потому и такая ошибка добавьте к конфигу entry: js файл какой нибудь .